# Laravel session state is not persisting between refreshes

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm using Laravel 5.3. The session state is being destroyed on refresh. I've checked the permission of session folder and it is correct. I can also see that the encrypted files are present in the session folder.

Here is the route List[image: Routes]

Comment: Maybe you should define better how you implement your session (file I assume by encrypted files) where you put what in it etc. Note that `config/session.php` is overwritten by `.env`

Comment: In .env file SESSION_DRIVER=file

Comment: yeah I know and that is fine, my question was to expand on where you are using your session, show your code.

Comment: also, session life time etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited the title of your question to make it clearer and less emotional so that people will be more inclined to answer it. I also cleaned up the wording of your question. From the comments it seems like you will get good answers if you provide more information about how you are storing, recalling, and configuring sessions in your code. Good luck!